# AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'minute'

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror, python-datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe that looks like this

```
df

[output]:
date        time
2020-02-28  00:30:45
2020-02-28  00:30:45
2020-03-09  00:21:06
2020-03-09  00:21:06
2020-03-09  00:21:06
```

with

```
df.time.dtype

[output]: dtype('<m8[ns]')
```

I want to extract the minutes in the time variable with the following command

```
df.time.dt.minute
```

but instead, I have this error

> AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'minute'

Does someone know how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

your column 'time' is of dtype `timedelta` as the error tells you; you could use the `total_seconds()` method to convert to seconds and divide by 60 to get the minutes.

If you want a full-featured datetime column, combine 'date' and 'time'. Then you can use `.dt.minute`.

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.to_timedelta(['00:30:45','00:30:45','00:21:06','00:21:06','00:21:06']),
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020-02-28','2020-02-28','2020-03-09','2020-03-09','2020-03-09'])})

# to get the "total minutes":
df['minutes'] = df['time'].dt.total_seconds()/60
df['minutes']
# 0    30.75
# 1    30.75
# 2    21.10
# 3    21.10
# 4    21.10
# Name: minutes, dtype: float64
```

[[pd.Timedelta docs]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html)

```
# to get a column of dtype datetime:
df['DateTime'] = df['date'] + df['time']

# now you can do:
df['DateTime'].dt.minute
# 0    30
# 1    30
# 2    21
# 3    21
# 4    21
# Name: DateTime, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have not converted to a datetime dataframe do that first 
then you create a new column like this

```
df['minute'] = df['date'].dt.minute
```

or this method here

```
  df[new]= df[column].map(lambda x: datetime.datetime(x.minutes))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just tried and now it gives me the "AttributeError: 'Timedelta' object has no attribute 'minutes'" error. I don't understand the difference between 'Timedelta' and 'TimedeltaProperties'.

Answer (score 3):

@Fobersteiner's answer is very good, but just for completeness, I would like to add that you could also divide your column of dtype `timedelta` by a fixed `timedelta`. For instance:

```py
from datetime import timedelta
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': pd.to_timedelta(['00:30:45','00:30:45','00:21:06','00:21:06','00:21:06']),
                   'date': pd.to_datetime(['2020-02-28','2020-02-28','2020-03-09','2020-03-09','2020-03-09'])})

# to get the "total minutes":
df['minutes'] = df['time'] / timedelta(minutes=1)  # <--
df['minutes']

Out[9]: 
0    30.75
1    30.75
2    21.10
3    21.10
4    21.10
Name: minutes, dtype: float64
```

Though personally, I prefer @Fobersteiner's method.