# How to transform these columns in time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I am doind some Data Exploratory Analysis to a dataset with columns with date with this format:

```
0       2020-02-25 00:29:00
1       2020-02-24 23:50:00
2       2020-02-25 00:31:00
3       2020-02-25 02:03:00
4       2020-02-25 03:51:00
```

Doing the substraction columnc = column A -column B, I get:

```
0              0 days 00:51:00
1       0 days 01:05:12.207000
2       0 days 00:50:41.817000
3              0 days 00:23:00
```

I'd like to transform this column C in minutes, for example but I don't find the way to declare the days in the conversion. I found this topic: [How to convert datetime to integer in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28154066/how-to-convert-datetime-to-integer-in-python) but it doesn't include days and I don't have same separators, Is it possible or do I have to change the column A and B somehow?

Thank as usual,

This community is very useful for people who are getting into the topic.

Comment: What is column A, B, C?

Comment: Is it not an option for you to convert the columns to minutes, and THEN substracting it? that way you wouldnt have to deal with the `days` at all - e.g. by converting it all to unix timestamps, then substract, then convert it back?

Comment: Where is column B?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62281476/attributeerror-timedeltaproperties-object-has-no-attribute-minute)

Comment: Sorry @Luke . My columns are datetime, just timestamp and I want to get the difference between them.

Comment: @Umar.H my column B is a vector of timestamp as well

Comment: @MrFuppes it could have been, I'll try as well. Thank to all of you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `dt.total_seconds() / 60`:

```
>>> df.dt.total_seconds() / 60
0    51.00000
1    65.20345
2    50.69695
3    23.00000
dtype: float64
>>>
```

Simply get the total seconds and divide it by 60 to get the minutes.

If you don't want the extra decimal points, try:

```
>>> df.dt.total_seconds().astype(int) // 60
0    51
1    65
2    50
3    23
dtype: int32
>>>
```

Comment: That's good, it worked! I didn't know this total_seconds function exists, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

While I am unsure of your exact date-formats (is it a datetime object? is it just a string?), assuming it is a string here, initially you want to convert it to a datetime object:

```
datetime_object = datetime.strptime('2020-02-25 00:29:00', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

After converting, (or if you already have a datetime object), you can subtract them:

```
timedelta_object = datetime_object2-datetime_object1
```

Finally, you can convert the timedelta into minute:

```
diff_minutes = timedelta_object.total_seconds()/60
```

Edit: Just before submitting I just saw that U12-Forward has already posted an answer that contains the same information here mostly, but I will keep my answer as well as it contains a bit more details.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I am a bit new...the type of the column is datetime object, so it worked as well, thank you

Answer (score 1):

assuming your dataframe looks like this (i've just subtracted 4 days from Col A)

```
             Column A            Column B
0 2020-02-25 00:29:00 2020-02-21 00:29:00
1 2020-02-24 23:50:00 2020-02-20 23:50:00
2 2020-02-25 00:31:00 2020-02-21 00:31:00
3 2020-02-25 02:03:00 2020-02-21 02:03:00
4 2020-02-25 03:51:00 2020-02-21 03:51:00
```

---

we can use `numpy` to get your timedelta as an integer.

using `np.timedelta64` and passing the arguments `1` `m` where `m` = `minute`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['minute_delta'] = (df['Column A'] - df['Column B']) / np.timedelta64(1,'m')

             Column A            Column B  minute_delta
0 2020-02-25 00:29:00 2020-02-21 00:29:00        5760.0
1 2020-02-24 23:50:00 2020-02-20 23:50:00        5760.0
2 2020-02-25 00:31:00 2020-02-21 00:31:00        5760.0
3 2020-02-25 02:03:00 2020-02-21 02:03:00        5760.0
4 2020-02-25 03:51:00 2020-02-21 03:51:00        5760.0
```

Comment: This is another option and it worked as well. Thank you too. I jot down the function it is quite interesting.

Comment: @Enrique your'e welcome :) you can also change the `'m`` in the `np.timedelta` to get the days as an integer, or hours,years,days etc :) try changing it around

Comment: Function is good, for the analysis I am doing I need it either in minutes or seconds but I'll use it for sure in the future. Thanks

Comment: change `m` to `s` and you'll get seconds ;) good luck!